# I am writing a code to store an int array in a file and then retrieve it in c++, but on retrieving the first item is bogus value, how do i fix this?

Tags: c++

I am trying to store integer array in a file in c++. 
the code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int arr[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    ofstream out;
    out.open("arr.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        out << arr[i];
    }
    out.close();

    ifstream in;
    in.open("arr.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        in>>arr[i];
    }
    in.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << i << " " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output i am getting is

```
01234
1234
1
2
3
4
```

where is the zero in the first index?

Comment: Not sure that I get your question, the zero comes from first loop.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the code. The code outputs `i` before each array value, but this isn't shown in your output.

Comment: @interjay That is because ideone does not support files so the code does nothing: https://ideone.com/gLHbFH

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I deleted that comment. What confused me is that the output shown in the question could not possibly have resulted from this code, whether files are supported or not.

Answer (score 7):

When you write the data, you're going to need to put whitespace between the numbers

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    out << arr[i] << ' ';
}
```

Otherwise they'll be read in as a single `int` all at once.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add spaces to your output.  When you do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    out << arr[i];
}
```

`arr` contains `{0,1,2,3,4}` so you write to the file `01234` and when you read that back with

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    in>>arr[i];
}
```

The whole `01234` is tread as a single integer of the value `1234` instead of reading each digit as a seperate number.  Changing your output loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    out << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

will make the file have `0 1 2 3 4` and then those will be read in as separate integers.

Comment: Ok i understand i have to store the integers in the file with spaces. But how do i retrieve the integers from the file and store them back to the array?

Comment: @RajaRoshaan You loop does that already.  `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    in>>arr[i];
}` says to read in 5 white space separated integers and that is what you have once you add spaces to your output loop.